# How frequently the UIPanGestureRecognizer gives a callback?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in my application. 
I have to  stop panning a view based on translation values that I get. This is the simple piece of code.

```
-(void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer) gestureRecognizer {
 CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
 if( ((someFixedPoint.center.y - currentYCoord + translation.y) <  A_FIXED_DISTANCE ) ) 
 {
 [view setCenter:[fixedX, currentYCoord + translation.y];
 }
}
```

The problem is `translation.y` returns different values every time when I pan fast. It works fine if I pan slowly since `**translation.y**` gives consistent values (For ex 23,24,25... as I pan). But if I pan fast it  gives different values every time (For Ex 23,29,34...) in one run and (27,31, 35..) in other run. So the last center before the **If  statement** becomes false is set at a different point every time I pan fast.
How can I make sure that last center set is at the same max point every time irrespective of my speed of panning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callbacks are determined by the scan rate of the hardware. You can't change that. So, change your algorithm to detect a translation `>=` your limit and then peg it to that limit.

I.e don't directly use `translation.y` to calculate the center, use `MIN(translation.y, MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: thanks Wain for the simple solution. I could not think of it. Damn!